# How do convert the output of a nested for loop into a list in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-loops

I am very new to Python so apologies for this basic question. I am trying to match columns of keywords with a list of text. If the keyword(s) can be found in the text, these should be appended to the spreadsheet which currently ends at the 'Engagement' column.

I currently get the following error message in the 2nd line of the 'for-loop': *TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not float*

What's wrong with my code and how should I correct it? Thank you.

```
df_rawdata = pd.read_excel (r'test.xlsx', sheet_name ='rawdata')
my_rawdatalist = df_rawdata['Text'].tolist()


df_all_words = pd.read_excel (r'test.xlsx', sheet_name ='pet_dict')

keywords_list = set(df_all_words['Animals'].tolist()+df_all_words['Cities'].tolist())

matchlist = []

for rawdata in my_rawdatalist:
        matches = [keyword for keyword in keywords_list if keyword in rawdata]
        matchlist.append("|".join(matches))

print(matchlist)
```

[image]

Comment: Can a element of `my_rawdatalist` have more than one `keyword` in it and if so, what should happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a list comprehension might go a long way to making this easier. Note that it will also allow you to deal with a phrase that contains multiple keywords:

```
my_rawdatalist = [
    "The cat is out",
    "The zoo is fun",
    "The dog is tired",
    "The dog chases the cat"
]
keywords_list = ["cat", "dog", "NaN"]
matchlist = []

for rawdata in my_rawdatalist:
    matches = [keyword for keyword in keywords_list if keyword in rawdata]
    matchlist.append("|".join(matches))

print(matchlist)
```

Will give you:

```
['cat', '', 'dog', 'cat|dog']
```

If you have "many" keywords, then you can cast your keyword_list to a `set()` as that will help make lookup more efficient.

```
keywords_list = set(["cat", "dog", "NaN"])
```

If you have multiple columns of keywords (if I understand what you are saying) then I would just append each column to the set.

```
keywords_list = set(
    ["cat", "dog", "NaN"] ## keywords from column A
    + ["Person", "Woman", "Man", "Camera", "TV"] ## keywords from column B
)
```

The code should continue to work:

```
my_rawdatalist = [
    "The cat is out",
    "The zoo is fun",
    "The dog is tired",
    "The dog chases the cat on TV"
]

keywords_list = set(
    ["cat", "dog", "NaN"] ## keywords from column A
    + ["Person", "Woman", "Man", "Camera", "TV"] ## keywords from column B
)

matchlist = []

for rawdata in my_rawdatalist:
    matches = [keyword for keyword in keywords_list if keyword in rawdata]
    matchlist.append("|".join(matches))

print(matchlist)
```

Gives you:

```
['cat', '', 'dog', 'dog|cat|TV']
```

Comment: Hi, How can this code be modified if there are multiple keyword columns that need to be matched with the same column of text? Turning the keywords into keyword:category dictionaries may work if you only have a couple of words to search for...but what if you have 100 words spread across many columns? Thank you.

Comment: I updated the answer to use a `set()` that might address performance concerns about "many" keywords.

Comment: Thank you JonSG, but I keep getting an error message in the for-loop. Can you help? Have updated the code in the example above so that it's easier for you/others to troubleshoot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I actually don't get why you want to have an empty string there, but maybe this helps you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.